# Restrict DD-WRT to VPN access

Tags: vpn, dd-wrt

I have got a few computers which I don't want to get online without VPN. They're on their own 192.168.1.0/24 subnet. How can I limit the internet access to only be able to connect to my VPN host?

The VPN I'm using randomly assigns an IP address from an IP pool to the computer.

How would you do that?